# copy constructor as templated member function is ignored

Tags: c++, templates

*Is it possible for assignment operator to be deduced as a special case of member function template?*

For example, I have a class template with one bool parameter and want to implement assign operation regardless any particular value of the template argument.

```
#include <iostream>

template<bool sw>
struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }

    template<bool input_sw>
    A & operator = (const A<input_sw> &a) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<true> a;
    A<true> b;
    a = b;
}
```

In the code snippet above clang and gcc-compiled binaries print out nothing about assignment -- as far as I can tell default assignment is generated here despite possibility to deduce it from the template.

Comment: A copy-assignment operator is a non-template function. There is still an implicitly generated copy-assignment operator that is called in your code. It is favorable to the written one because a non-template function is preferred over a template one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is correct for them to not print anything out. What is happening is that there is an *implicit* copy assignment operator created for `A<true>` with this signature:

```
A<true>& operator=(const A<true>& );
```

Thus, when we do overload resolution, there are two viable candidates:

```
A<true>& operator=(const A<true>& );     // implicit copy assignment
A<true>& operator=(const A<input_sw>& ); // [ with input_sw = true ]
```

Both operators take the same argument (`const A<true>&`), so they are equivalently good candidates from this perspective. But non template functions are preferred to function template specializations, which makes the implicit copy assignment operator the *best* viable candidate.

---

Now, consider an alternative. What if you declared your operator template this way:

```
template<bool input_sw>
A & operator =(A<input_sw> &a) { ... }
```

That is, not `const`. This isn't good practice, and I'm presenting this solely for illustrative purposes. In this case, our two candidates for `a=b` are:

```
A<true>& operator=(const A<true>& );   // implicit copy assignment
A<true>& operator=(A<input_sw>& );     // [ with input_sw = true ]
```

Now the two candidates do *not* take the same argument. Our operator template takes a reference to non-`const`. In the case of two references, the one referring to the last *cv*-qualified type is preferred, which in this case would be the operator. Drop that `const`, and now your function is preferred, and you will see something printed.

C++ is the best.

Comment: I suppose, explicitly deleting of default assignment operator won't help? Is it possible to remove the default one from overload resolution?

Comment: @AlexanderSergeev No. If there is an implicit assignment operator, it will be either defaulted or deleted.

Comment: @AlexanderSergeev Put the logic for assignment in a templated member function, and redirect both operators to it. Or can you design the class such that the default assignment operator is indeed correct?

Comment: @NeilKirk Yes, redirecting to a common implementation is an option, but I just wanted to use a solution with as small number of utility code/functions as possible; the default-generated operator is not correct because of resource management (deep copying and so on).

Comment: @AlexanderSergeev You can use smart pointers and containers to perform the deep copying for you and then the default-generated ones will work automatically.

Comment: @NeilKirk, smart pointers are in use, but using default assign operator I still would need an additional function to assign object with different sw value (for this particular source snippet). So more unificated way is preferrable.

Comment: @AlexanderSergeev Yes you would, but the fact the default-generated assignment operator for when the `sw` values are the same, shouldn't matter any more?

Comment: @NeilKirk I think it is more like matter of taste at this level of details about implementation.